# Is satisficing conceptualised as being unconscious/automatic, or conscious/volitional?

Tags: consciousness, bias

I haven't found anything that speaks directly to this question, but here is the account Simon (1990) p9 provides of satisficing

> If the task domain has little structure or the structure is unknown to
>   us, we apply so-called "weak methods," which experience has shown to
>   be useful in many domains, but which may still require us to search a
>   good deal. One weak method is satisficing--using experience to
>   construct an expectation of how good a solution we might reasonably
>   achieve, and halting search as soon as a solution is reached that
>   meets the expectation.

Simon, H. A. (1990). Invariants of human behavior. Annual review of psychology, 41(1), 1-20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Satisficing is goal directed and satisficers intend to achieve satisfactory results. Therefore, satisficing seems to involve conscious choices being made.

However, in Unconscious Thought Theory (UTT), [unconscious thought produces superior decisions compared to conscious thought when decision making is complex](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cG49BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA233) and there are paragraphs of [Nelson and Winter (1982)](http://inctpped.ie.ufrj.br/spiderweb/pdf_2/Dosi_1_An_evolutionary-theory-of_economic_change..pdf) that indicate that satisficing can be achieved from a sequence of mechanical, automatic steps of rule following.

Therefore looking at both H.A. Simon's conception and the findings from Nelson and Winter, satisficing can be either conscious or unconscious.